# An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

Accedentially I have deleted tables on my DB on aws react native and when I run command: "amplify push" its giving me following error:

```
An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:899175426651:stack/amplify-imedia-dev-181304/da123e60-1238-11ec-953b-0a632af20480 is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state and can not be updated.
An error occurred during the push operation: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:899175426651:stack/amplify-imedia-dev-181304/da123e60-1238-11ec-953b-0a632af20480 is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state and can not be updated.
```

Comment: Van you share the error message by going to the cloudformation service page in the console, then select the stack that is failed, and then go to the "events" tab. It should mention which resource failed to roll back and the reason of the rollback. Then you know what to remediate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: often I find the easiest way to debug is to find the first error message that amplify cli prints into the console after i run amplify push. Look at the cli after you have run amplify push, and confirmed all the questions, suddenly one of the lines turns red (the error message), and that first line that turns red are usually your best clue to look at what the error is.